# python datetime.timedelta - how to display in form <seconds>.<micros>

Tags: python, python-2.6

If I have a datetime.timedelta of:
datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 66)

> print my_dt 
>   0:00:00.000066

How can I keep and print just the seconds and the microseconds together? (i.e. strip the mins and hours).

I can see how to take just the micro and or the seconds, i.e. by those objects (e.g. `my_dt.microseconds`) - but I would like to keep both in the same cmd  without any ugly formatting, sticking strings together after the fact.

For this example the output I am after would be:

> 00.000066

Any help appreciated (python n00b)

Version:

- Python 2.6.6

Comment: Sorry -0 yiou want to format the output without using formatting strings? Can you clarify on that?

Comment: Also, why are y9u using Python2.6 that is quite an old version (no, it is not the "second to last", the newest version is 3.5, and 2.6 is 6 versions behind that - it is ok to use 2.7 if you have thngs that need Python 2, but you really should not)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the official documentation for datetime util.

[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

If you have a timedelta objects, it means that you've have a time interval which is stable. timedelta object has 3 attributes: days, seconds and microseconds.

For example: If your time interval is 1 day, 5 hours, 23 minutes, 10 seconds and 50 microseconds; do you want the output format to be only `10.000050` ?
I'm guessing like the above.

So your code should be like:

```
seconds = my_dt.seconds%60
microseconds = my_dt.microseconds%1000000
result = "%d.%d" %(seconds,microseconds)
```

Comment: you really sshouldues  the string interpolation with the `.format` string method - or the `%` string operator, isntead of concatenating strings like this.

Comment: That's another way but would this be a problem ? I use also like this and haven't encountered any problem until now.

Comment: Ok I fixed the format but I'm just wondering would it be a problem to cast an integer to a string? If so, I've used this method couple of times in my project. I might think of changing them.

Comment: No  - the string formatting "%d" takes care of the needed conversions. That is the idea behind a very-high-level language: this i sn ot casting, the "%d" formatting expects a numeric value.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I worked with java a lot and still learning python. I'll do like this next time.